# Conditional routing to a page validating against JSON data

Tags: json, reactjs, react-router, gatsby

I'm new to React, so go easy on me! I'm basically looking for the simplest way to 'route' to a specific page in Gatsby, based on a range of codes entered. I could do this simply with jQuery, validating against a .json file full of codes, however I'd rather challenge myself and do this in React.

What I'm looking to achieve:

1. User arrives at blank page with text input and button.
2. User enters code.
3. App checks code from list of codes in a .json file.
4. App routes to and displays page corresponding to the code entered.

Does anybody know of any decent or similar tutorials on how to achieve something like this? Do I need to use React Router or can Gatsby handle this out of the box? Apologies for sounding like a noob - any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I've got a really barebones app up and running fine:
https://gist.github.com/cruelmelody/fc5a1eb6d34118b76d7c273c813a0ec2

The below is a sample of the .json data being mapped:

```js
[
    {
        "code": "401BE001",
        "activation": "story1"
    },
    {
        "code": "401BE002",
        "activation": "story2"
    }
]
```

Where I'm stuck is matching the JSON object to the input value string. Where am I going wrong?

```
  if ({this.state.barcodeReceiptNo} === {beadCode.code}) {
      alert("It's a match!")
  } else {
      alert("Unlucky.")
  }
```

Thanks for your help.

Mark.

Comment: Have you tried coding this, a sample would be great to guide you in the right direction. Anyway, to make it dynamic, you should import your json file to route component, `map` all routes and handle `redirect` if no route matches.

Comment: @jank I'm very much looking for a starting point. Conceptualising how the router works is where I am struggling, but this sounds promising. React is a different way of thinking for me.

Comment: @jank I've had a go at coding this as per the above. Hopefully this provides a bit more context!

Answer (score 1):

Gatbsy have `@reach/router` included so you can do it without any extra library.

1. Create a file under `pages` section, where your user will land on first load.
2. `import { navigate } from 'gatsby'`
3. Set a form to collect user input.
4. Import your JSON file with codes and paths.
5. Compare your JSON file and your user input, and call `() => navigate(path)` on button click.

The only caveats here is, as Gatsby is a static site generator, all of the paths should exist beforehand (one file per page, under `pages` directory with the same name as the `path` value you are passing to `navigate`).

If the `path/file` doesn't exist, it will return a 404.

Look for programmatic routing in Gatsby official docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/